# Access BlocProvider.of in routes which are outside the initial flow of the application

Tags: flutter, bloc

I need the `UserBloc` to be accessible globally around my `App` because it seems like is not possible to access a `BlocProvider` in routes which are not directly dependent on the main widget tree.

The WidgetTree structure of my app (*the relevant part*) right now is:

```
App
├── HomePage
│   └── LessonPage
└── ProfilePage
```

From the `LessonPage` is possible to **navigate** to the `ProfilePage` but this breaks the `child-parent` relationship for which you can call `BlocProvider.of`.

So i wonder how should I handle this properly.

The solution i'm using right now is the following, but this is causing me issues since `close` of `UserBloc` is never called since `App` is never really disposed, leaving the `Stream` open when it should not.

```dart
runApp(MultiBlocProvider(
        providers: [
          BlocProvider<AuthBloc>(
            create: (context) =>
                AuthBloc(authRepository: authRepository)..add(AppStarted()),
          ),
          //.. other BlocProvider not relevant to this question ..
        ],
        child: BlocProvider<UserBloc>(
          create: (BuildContext context) => UserBloc(
            userRepository: UserRepository(),
            authBloc: BlocProvider.of<AuthBloc>(context),
          ),
          child: App(
            authRepository: authRepository,
          ),
        )));
  });
```

Another possible solution i'm seeing here it will be to handle this in the route handler, for instance:

```dart
  //... some more code...
  @override
  HandlerFunc get handlerFunc => (BuildContext context, Map<String, List<String>> params) {
    return BlocProvider<UserBloc>(
        create: (BuildContext context) => UserBloc(
          userRepository: UserRepository(),
          authBloc: BlocProvider.of<AuthBloc>(context),
        ),child: ProfilePage(email: params[email][0])
    );
  };
}
```

But this will create several instances of the `UserBloc` which will have to call close as much time as they got instantiated basically performing, at best, useless operations.

I don't really like neither of the 2 solution, that's why i'm seeking for help.

***Note**: for handling routes i'm using https://pub.dev/packages/fluro so that method handleFunc is taken from that, it will simply be called on `Navigator.pushNamed` of any registered route.

Which one is the advisable approach?
Any other solution i'm not seeing here?

Thank you in advance for your help!